Using a mask for texture painting doesnt reveal or hide the textures
I have 2 textures plugged into a mix shader node. I added an image node texture with a black mask, and when I try to use the texture paint method to draw on the texture to make a shape, nothing is happening.



Also I'm toggling on and off the image mask, and I can see a strip has been created, as I'm trying to figure out, why I cannot see this in real time.

Basically I cannot see anything wrong in your setup, last time I actually used it was in an older version but now I just tested it in 4.2.0 and it still works. The only thing I notice is that when I for example paint in Rendered view, the result is not immediately visible. I have to switch to Material Preview and then back to Rendered to refresh the view. But you are in Material Preview so this should work... maybe you need to upload your file...? texture painting mask

Just saw your edit. Well, if you are painting with the Image Texture node muted, then of course it does not show the result... neither while painting nor after painting.

In that last picture to the lower right, your brush has a solid black texture on it - that is like masking the entire brush from working. Get rid of that and try again.

Yes, good spotting, I deleted it, and then was able to use the brush. I dont know how I had clicked to make it a mask, but I deleted it, and then the brush worked. Thank you.
